# PowerApps - create my own table or use a Dataverse table?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, common-data-service, dataverse

I have a couple of questions regarding PowerApps and the Dataverse.  I don't know where else to ask them.  I'm hoping someone here can help me.

I'm very familiar with creating a database in MS SQL SERVER.  I've been doing that for 20+ years.  I'm used to creating/seeing a database diagram that shows what tables are in the database and how they are related.  Documentation about each table, what is it's business purpose etc..  Documentation about each column - what it's purpose is, it's domain of values etc.

Where do I find this same sort of documentation for the Dataverse?  I've been searching for days and have not come across one schema diagram showing what tables are in the Dataverse or how they are related.  Nor have I found any documentation that describes the business purpose of the tables or columns.

How would I know if I should create a table in the Dataverse for some business function or whether I should be using a table that already exits e.g. Company (to capture information about companies my organization cares about), Org Unit (to capture information about the org structure of my company), Staff (to capture information about staff in my company and what org unit they belong to), Business process (to capture information about processes executed by org units in my company)...

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

Dataverse (earlier called as Common Data service) is nothing but Dynamics CRM under the hood. So you can [start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/data-platform-intro#interacting-with-tables) and you can find the Entity/Table metadata details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/reference/entities/account)

If you are looking for ERD, then I will use [XrmToolBox - ERD Visio Builder](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/LinkeD365.ERDVisioBuilder/) to connect and pull it.